# Why would an XMLListCollection get corrupted by addItamAt function in Flash Builder 4.6

Tags: flash-builder

The XMLListCollection in question is called studentsAll and looks like this after being created...

```
<details>
   <name>Baughman,  John D (@hawaii.rr.com at Pearl City H. S.)</name>
   <id>2693</id>
   <emailpw>johnbdh@hawaii.rr.com</emailpw>
   <pw/>
 </details>
 <details>
    <name>Benoit, Sandra (@gmail.com at Pearl City H. S.)</name>
    <id>2694</id>
    <emailpw>sandra@gmail.com</emailpw>
    <pw/>
 </details>
```

I am then runniing...

```
studentsList = new XMLListCollection;
studentsIDs = new XMLListCollection;

for (var _index:int=0; _index < studentsAll.length; _index++) {
    studentsList.addItemAt(studentsAll[_index].name, studentsList.length);
    studentsIDs.addItemAt(studentsAll[_index].id, studentsIDs.length);

}
```

Wehn that finishes the XMLListCollection studentsAll looks like this...

```
<details>
    <name>Baughman,  John D (@hawaii.rr.com at Pearl City H. S.)</name>
    <name>Benoit, Sandra (@gmail.com at Pearl City H. S.)</name>
    <id>2693</id>
    <id>2694</id>
    <emailpw>johnbdh@hawaii.rr.com</emailpw>
    <pw/>
</details>
<details>
     <name>Benoit, Sandra (@gmail.com at Pearl City H. S.)</name>
     <id>2694</id>
     <emailpw>sandra@gmail.com</emailpw>
     <pw/>
</details>
```

Notice how the tags in the second index have been duplicated in the first.

Is this a bug?

Thanks,

John

Comment: Why are there missing () after new XMLListCollection? Also do you need to use addItemAt instead of addItem?

Comment: You are right I seem to have left () out in a lot of places, but it doesn't seem to matter one way or the other. I have fixed them all now. As for the addItemAt isn't that what I have in my example code? Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this is caused by a SDK bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-33913

A pretty nasty bug; personally, I now don't trust XMLListCollection at all.

**Workarounds:**
Use XMLList, Array or ArrayCollection instead of XMLListCollection or run the `for` loop on a cloned collection - use `.copy()`